# Blur a button in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, blur, effects

Can I blur a button in C# using windows forms?

I know it is possible using WPF, but I am using winforms for my current project.

If not, there's any way to put a WPF button in a winforms Form?

Comment: this may be relevant for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598772/layer-effects-blur-etc-in-winforms

Comment: Pretty trivial with the Button.Image property.  Use ElementHost to use a WPF button.

Comment: You mean "make visually blurry" and not "remove input focus," right?

Comment: Yes @adv12. Really, I want to make an effect like windows taskbar.